# How can I get element of list

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have an array with 3 elements, I use `for`-loop to remove `"1", "2"` but `if`-condition always false. What's the problem?

```
string[] listCountAnwser = {"1", "2", "3"};
List<string> listCountAnwsers = new List<string>(listCountAnwser);
for (int i = 0; i < listCountAnwsers.Count; i++)
{
    if (Int32.Parse(listCountAnwsers[i]) < Int32.Parse(listCountAnwsers[i++]))
    {
        listCountAnwsers.Add(listCountAnwser[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things caught my eye.
At first, you are wrong to use the increment operator. To make sure run this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listCountAnwsers.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(listCountAnwsers[i] + "\t" + listCountAnwsers[i++]);
```

The **output** will be like:

```
1    1
3    3
```

That is why your code never enters the `if`-condition.
Another problem is that you remove elemets. This entails changing the `listCountAnwsers.Count` property of list. To make sure:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
{
    listCountAnwsers.Remove(listCountAnwsers[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(listCountAnwsers.Count);
}
```

The **output**:

```
2
1
```

Then the **exception** like `argument out of range`. Indeed. Also you can get such exception when you will try something like this:

```
if (Int32.Parse(listCountAnwsers[i]) < Int32.Parse(listCountAnwsers[i + 1]))
    listCountAnwsers.Remove(listCountAnwser[i]);
```

So the solving of your problem depends on what you need at all. What elements do you want to have at the result? Please clarify

Comment: That is my mistake. My code should be "listCountAnwsers.Add(listCountAnwser[i]);"

Comment: @BinhHuynh Ok, you can clarify your question if you still have some issues. And I will try to help you. Apparently, the problem solved just by replacing `i++` on `i + 1`..

Comment: I have replaced i++ by i+1 and It worked
Thank for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try this. `i++` increase the value of i after check in the condition. So you need to use `i+1`

```
string[] listCountAnwser = {"1", "2", "3"};
List<string> listCountAnwsers = new List<string>(listCountAnwser);
for (int i = 0; i < listCountAnwsers.Count; i++)
{
    if (Int32.Parse(listCountAnwsers[i]) < Int32.Parse(listCountAnwsers[i+1]))
    {
        listCountAnwsers.Add(listCountAnwser[i]);
     }
 }
```